# Tool-tip does not hide sometimes

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

[image: bootstrap tooltip]

As shown in above screenshot that `bootstrap` does not hide. I am using below code:

```
$this.tooltip({
                                    'placement': function (tip, element) {
                                        var position = $(element).position();
                                        if ((position.top) + 150 > $(window).height()) {
                                            return "top"
                                        }
                                        return "bottom"
                                    },
                                    'title': $this.attr("title"),
                                    'trigger': 'hover',
                                    'animation': true,
                                    'html': true
                                });
```

**What could be the issue and how do I resolve this ???**

`Chrome Version 38.0.2125.111 m`

Comment: Make working fiddle and let me know

Comment: codepen.io or jsfiddle.net = Put code in one of these

Comment: not able to post on jsfiddle as the issue comes on production only.

Comment: try removing this 3 properties 'trigger': 'hover',
                                    'animation': true,
                                    'html': true